# we throw $n$ uniform dices each with $m$ diffferent faces

Tags: probability, dice

I'm having a hard time solving the following problem :

We have $n$ uniform dices, each with $m$ different faces.
We throw the dices simultaneously and see what comes out. Then we order the results in increasing order to get a number read in base $m$. Call this $r$. What is the average of $r$?

I thought of representing $r$ as a random variable and calculate the mean, but I'm not sure how. The problem is that some faces may appear more than one time, and that's what makes the problem hard. There's an intuitive trick that I failed to see here.

Comment: Are the dices faces numbered from $0$ to $m-1$, then?

Comment: Take the mean of each digit individually and then add them up?

Comment: Isn't this also a bit problematic, since the digits are sorted in increasing order?

Comment: What average is desired in the question?  I usually assume mean unless otherwise specified, but you mention median.  I think the median makes it easier, otherwise this looks like a very messy problem.  If $m=2$ you are averaging the binary numbers with all the $0$s preceding all the $1$s.  You can establish a bijection between the results with less than $n/2$ $1$s with those with less than $n/2$ $0$s, so the median is ???  Can you extend this?

Comment: @leonbloy   yes the digits are from 0 to m-1 for example for n=3 and m=5
the faces are from 0 to 4, and if the dices show "1", "4", "2" then we get the number "124" in base 5

Comment: @Ross Millikan  actually the problem didn't specify the average, but i mistyped it, Where i live (France) the average always mean the mean in a mathematical problem, i edited it

Answer (score 1):

Here is how far I was able to simplify, perhaps there is an easier way to do this:

Let $X_k$ denote the outcome of dice $k$. Then $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are IID with uniform distribution, and $P(X_k=j) = m^{-1}$ for each $k=1,\dots,n$ and $j=0,\dots,m-1$. Let $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ be the order statistics of $X_1,\dots,X_n$ (i.e., $Y_1$ is the smallest of $X_1,\dots,X_n$, and $Y_2$ is the next smallest, all the way to $Y_n$ being the largest). Then it holds
$$R = Y_nm^{n-1} + \cdots + Y_2m + Y_1 \implies \mathbb E[R] = \sum_{k=1}^n\mathbb E[Y_k]m^{k-1}.$$
From the [wikipedia page on order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic), the CDF of $Y_k$ is given by
$$P(Y_k \leq x) = \sum_{j=k}^n\binom{n}{j}\left(\frac{x}{m}\right)^j\left(1-\frac{x}{m}\right)^{n-j}, \quad x=0,\dots,m.$$
If $Z_x\sim\text{Binom}(n,x/m)$, then we see $P(Y_k \leq x) = P(Z_x \geq k).$ Thus we have
$$\mathbb E[Y_k] = \sum_{x=1}^mP(Y_k \geq x) = \sum_{x=1}^m P(Z_x \leq k).$$
So,
$$\mathbb E[R] = \sum_{x=1}^m \sum_{k=1}^n P(Z_x \leq k)m^{k-1}.$$